# Saving each result on a new line to a csv file, using python

Tags: python, file, csv

I've been trying to create a csv file using python and save a new date on a new row. My intention is to replicate the shell output(shown below), in csv file. However the output I get is only saving the last result and iterating through one date(shown in the csv output below). I'm sure there's an error in my approach but I'm stumped. thanks in advance.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
import csv

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2014, 12, 28)
end_date = date(2015, 1, 10)

for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    new_date = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(new_date)
```

[shell output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg6Le.png)    [csv output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHTHg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a file with `w` mode, python truncates the file.  You should open it only once:

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        new_date = single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        writer.writerow(new_date)
```

Comment: Cheers @zondo that works well but each integer now has it's own cell along a row. is there a way to get the whole date in one cell? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes.  Below the `writer = csv.writer(f)` line, say `dates = []`.  Then instead of saying `new_date = single_date...`, say `dates.append(single_date...)`.  Take out the `writer.writerow(new_date)` line and put `writer.writerows(dates)` just outside of the `for` loop.  (after it)